# is there any difference with joint primary key order?

Tags: mysql

I am curious about that , is there any difference with joint primary key order?
For example, is there any difference between the two tables' primary key? the key order would make no difference on the table?

```
CREATE TABLE `Q3` (
    `user_id` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `retweet_id` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`retweet_id`)
    )
```

vs

```
CREATE TABLE `Q3` (
    `user_id` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `retweet_id` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`retweet_id`,`user_id`)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make difference in an index structure.

In composite index the index value consists of several values that go one after another. And the order determines what queries can be optimized using this particular index.

IE:

For the index created as

```
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`retweet_id`)
```

The query like `WHERE user_id = 42` will be optimized (not guaranteed, but technically possible), whereas for the query `WHERE retweet_id = 4242` it won't be.

PS: it's a good idea to always have an artificial primary key, like a sequence (or an autoincrement column in case of mysql), instead of using natural primary keys. It would be better because the primary key is a clustered key, which means it defines how rows are physically stored in pages on disk. Which means it's a good idea for a PK to be monotonously growing (or decreasing, doesn't matter)

Comment: Hi,if i have user_id retweetUserId 1000017114 419841271 in one row ,and also have 419841271 1000017114 in another row, so can I use PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`retweetUser_id`) ,by that I mean does the primary key unique since the user_id and retweetUser_id just exchanged the place in another row?

Comment: @user3147438: you can have it, order matters.

Answer (score 0):

The order does affect how the index is used in queries.  When you use multiple columns, each column is a sub-tree of the preceding column.

In your first case (user_id, retweet_id) - if you searched the index for user_id 1, you then have all the retweet_ids under that.

Subsequently if you wish to search for only retweet_id=7 (for all users) - the index cannot be used because you need to first step through each users item in the index.

So if you wish to query for user_id, or retweet_id individually (without the other), put that column first.  If you need both you could consider adding a secondary index.

There are also limitations for range scans, you can only effectively use the last column queried for the range scan.  You can read more about all of this here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Additionally if using InnoDB, the tables are stored in order of the PRIMARY KEY.  This might matter for performance depending on how you query your data.